# Django SerializerDoesNotExist 'geojson'?

Tags: django, serialization, geojson, gdal

I'm trying to serialize data in the geojson format however whenever I use

```
json = serialize("geojson", coordinate.objects.all())
response = HttpResponse(json)
return response
```

django gives me

**SerializerDoesNotExist at /getmarkers/
'geojson'**

this works fine

```
json = serialize("json", coordinate.objects.all())
```

surely anyone else who has tried using the geojson serializer has ran into the same issue. I've installed the GDAL library as told to do so in the docs. Any ideas? Can't seem to really find anything in the docs about what modules must be imported I've tried

```
from django.contrib.gis import gdal
```

Does not throw an error but also does not fix the issue
I'm using Django 1.8

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to include the geojson serializer in settings.py

```
SERIALIZATION_MODULES = {
    "geojson": "django.contrib.gis.serializers.geojson", 
 }
```

Comment: Django should really include this in the [geojson serializer docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/serializers/#). If it weren't for this post, I'd still be looking too.